# Image Processing - OpenCV - Finding the area and center coordinates of circles in an image

Tags: c++, opencv, geometry, area, hough-transform

I have an image file.There are a few filled circles and rectangles in it.The fill color is blue.The radius of the circles can vary.The background is white.I need to find:

1. The center coordinates of each circle.
2. The area of each circle.

How can I do it?
I'm using OpenCV with C++
Could you please write a code and explain..
Or please give me some search points..like what functions to use etc

I'm new to OpenCV and Stackoverflow...
Thanks..

Comment: can you provide a sample image?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has something called [Hough Circle Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

On that link there is example code which:

1. Loads an image and blur it to reduce the noise
2. Applies the Hough Circle Transform to the blurred image .
3. Display the detected circle in a window.

The key part is:

```
  /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
  HoughCircles( src_gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, src_gray.rows/8, 200, 100, 0, 0 );

  /// Draw the circles detected
  for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ )
  {
      Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
      int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
      // circle center
      circle( src, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
      // circle outline
      circle( src, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
   }

  /// Show your results
  namedWindow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "Hough Circle Transform Demo", src );
```